# Retain focus of Child window after parent and child windows are refreshed

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, internet-explorer, popupwindow

In my scenario, I have the main window (parent) with a button. When I click on that, it results in opening of a sub-window (child) with some input to be taken and contains a **Submit** button.

When I provide the input and click on the **Submit** button, the business logic gets executed and both the pages get refreshed (first, the child gets refreshed, then the parent gets refreshed), but I want the child to be retained at the foreground, which doesn't happen in IE browsers.

What should I do to retain my child window even after clicking on **Submit** button? Info: When I click on submit button, Struts Action execute() gets invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because when the parent window was refreshing, there was a checkbox which had focus on it by default. So IE would consider that as the current window.